# find rows that must have both values, not just one of them

Tags: mysql

i need to find rows that have both values, for example:

find all recipes that must contain flour and sugar in that recipe, but with my query i get all recipes that have sugar or flour.

here is my query:

```
select recipe_id, ingred_id from ingreds_values where  ingred_id in (3,17)
```

i get this results

```
recipe_id| ingred_id
12083    | 3
12083    | 17
2990     | 17
10084    | 17
3046     | 17
5244     | 3
5244     | 17
```

but i need to get this result:

```
recipe_id| ingred_id
    12083    | 3
    12083    | 17
    5244     | 3
    5244     | 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure a DBA or someone else will be able to create a much more elegant query for you, but this will do the trick:

```
select iv1.recipe_id, iv1.ingred_id, iv2.ingred_id
from
  ingreds_values iv1,
  ingreds_values iv2
where      
  iv1.recipe_id = iv2.recipe_id
  AND iv1.ingred_id in (3,17)
  AND iv1.ingred_id != iv2.ingred_id
  AND iv2.ingred_id in (3,17);
```

Your query is using the IN clause which is returning any row that has the inred_value as being 3 OR 17.  But what you need are recipes that have a record for BOTH 3 AND 17.

Comment: thank you. That is what i needed.

Comment: one more question. When i have more then 2 ingridents, like 3 or 4, then i am not sure how to implement your solution then?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the recipes, I would suggest using aggregation and `having`:

```
select recipe
from ingreds_values
where ingred_id in (3, 17)
group by recipe
having count(distinct ingred_id) = 2;
```

If you want the actual rows, you have several options.  How about this?

```
select iv.*
from ingreds_values iv
where exists (select 1 from ingreds_values iv2 where iv2.recipe = iv.recipe and iv2.ingred_id = 3) and
      exists (select 1 from ingreds_values iv2 where iv2.recipe = iv.recipe and iv2.ingred_id = 17) and
      iv.ingred_id in (3, 17);
```

Comment: first example still return recipes  with one of the ingredient, i need recipes with both ingridents only. Second example is very slow, and return again recipes with one of the ingrident

Comment: @gandrap . . . The first cannot return recipes with only one ingredient, because the `having` clause guarantees two.  This also readily generalizes to more ingredients.